# Locking a file for read/write with Node.js

Tags: node.js, unix, concurrency, locking

I am looking for the ability to do the following sequence of events:

I see the value in merely writing atomically, but are there any suggestions for

```
1. locking a file
2. reading from it
3. writing to it
4. releasing the lock
```

how do we do this (with Node.js)? Let's say this file stores simple JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

For even this simple use case, I believe you do need a locking mechanism if there are other processes concurrently accessing the file.

I tried out Lockfile and Warlock and was not impressed about their default settings and how difficult it was to fine tune them.

So I wrote a different kind of mutex library called "live-mutex" which allows for no polling and is a completely evented client-broker model. It's main claim to fame is that it's about 15x faster than both lockfile and warlock.

Check it out:
[Github.com/oresoftware/live-mutex](http://www.github.com/oresoftware/live-mutex)

Comment: You are very right - it's amazing that modules with millions of weekly downloads are of such pur quality or simply not working.

Your package seems impressive. But I prefer a solution for file locking that does not require a TCP port.
Do you have issues with fcntl advisory file locking?

Comment: live-mutex does not require a tcp port, you can use Unix Domain Sockets, and UDS is much more performant too, about 2x.

Comment: @SimonRigét try out live-mutex with UDS and see what you think

Answer (score 1):

You must ensure "atomic locks"  From inside node, you can use symlinks to achieve this. Here is an example of a simple counter:

```
const fs = require('fs');

// the lock function must be a recursive timer
const flock = (file_name, resolve, reject) => {
  fs.symlink(file_name, 'locked_' + file_name, (err) => {
    if(err)
      if(err.code == 'EEXIST')
        setTimeout(() => {
          flock(file_name, resolve, reject)
        }, 13);
      else
        reject(err);
    else
      resolve();
  });
}

const counter_increment = async () => {
  file_name = 'counter.txt';

  // Lock file
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    flock(file_name, resolve, reject);
  });

  // Read file
  let count = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(file_name, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) resolve(0);
      resolve(parseInt(data));
    });
  });

  // Write file
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile(file_name,"" + ++count + " ", (err) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve();
    });
  });

  // Unlock file
  fs.unlink('locked_' + file_name, (err) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
  });

  return count;
};

counter_increment();
```

This is slow compared to a real OS implementation of file lock, but it's working for production.

The node file system library is rather immature at this point. (As of node 11) This functionality should have been standard by now, but isn't.

The module fs.ext https://github.com/baudehlo/node-fs-ext/ adds the 
real OS file locking. Unfortunately there is a bug in the way i handles multiple requests, that makes it unusable in production. Further more, the maintainers don't seem to have the time to fix it.

All other modules I have come across, doesn't do a very good job of it. Even the very popular ones.

Comment: mkdir is an atomic operation, there is also this library which does locks across processes using TCP: https://github.com/ORESoftware/live-mutex

Comment: Any chance you have information on the multiple-request bug?

Comment: It's a design flaw/immaturity of the file functions in libuv, and thereby the method used in the module.
See: https://github.com/baudehlo/node-fs-ext/issues/79